# Can you retrieve url like history for Facebook over a period of time

Tags: facebook, twitter, statistics, linkedin-api, google-plus

I would like to know if anyone has figured out a way to retrieve a history of likes/shares on Facebook BEYOND a simple count. I'd like to be able to query all results over a period of time. For example, the query would need to get all likes (along with the date/time of the like) as well as the same for the shares. It would be *nice* to also get the names or user ids of the users that did the liking/sharing but that's not required.

The same would be nice for Twitter, Google+ and LinkedIn.

If anyone knows of the ways to do this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I just created a tool that gathers data similar to this, and some of what you want is possible, while other parts are not.

Facebook doesn't provide any method of tracking when a like happened from the perspective of the object being liked, unless you can authenticate as that object and read private notifications.

Many objects, like [PHOTOS](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/), you can find out who liked them by going through the likes connection.

Answer (score 0):

For Google+, if you also use Google Analytics on your site, you can use the Social section of Google Analytics to get an idea of your social metrics like +1s over time. Google Analytics also supports some metrics for Facebook, LinkedIn and other services.

See: http://www.google.com/analytics/features/social.html